# How do I upload API credentials to github so that my CI can see them, but so the average person cannot?

Tags: ruby, git, github, continuous-integration, secret-key

I am using an API and I have a secret key for this API. Obviously, I do not want everyone on github to be able to see my API secret key, but I want my CI to be able to see it for testing purposes. How can I do this? I am using Ruby and the API is Twilio if that makes any difference.

Comment: Your test should not run against a third party service. Mock the server and you don't need the credentials on the test system at all.

Comment: So pretty much test what I can, but assume the API itself works because it should?

Comment: Sure, otherwise your test would be unreasonable slow. Btw. how should developers run tests on their machines, when they don't have the credentials, but the test a build to run against the third party service.